# Examples of sans serif Greek used in published mathematics

Tags: notation, big-list

Unicode contains several thousand mathematical symbols, including individual code points for different maths alphabets. For example, U+1D434 is "mathematical italic capital A" (), U+1D63C is "math sans bold italic A" (), and so on.

Unfortunately, when mathematics coverage was extended to support all these alphabets, there was a notable omission. For Latin letters, there are glyphs for seven alphabets: italic, bold, bold italic, sans upright, sans italic, sans bold, sans bold italic.

However, Greek letters there are glyphs for only five different forms: italic, bold, bold italic, sans bold, sans bold italic (). There are no "sans upright" or "sans italic" Greek code points.

A number of us in the LaTeX community would like to add the "missing" sans Greek alphabets into Unicode. To have the Unicode Consortium accept the new alphabets, we need to be able to demonstrate examples in published mathematics where, say, a sans serif alpha was used in distinction to a regular italic alpha.

Have you seen such examples yourself? Any pointers to publications (snippets of equations even better) would be extremely helpful.

Comment: From what I've seen, poor adoption of the various forms means that more often than not, Greek letters are not even bolded, say, even when they should be; the difficulty of handwriting the various forms distinctly also adds to the lack of distinction. There also doesn't seem to be any consensus on whether the standard Greek letters should be italicised in the first place. Not really on topic, but there's anything Unicode should have added to it, it should be text figures, which were very poorly supported until OpenType provided a partial solution.

Comment: @Chappers — You're right, it's a chicken and egg problem. LaTeX+amsmath doesn't support lowercase sans Greek, so mathematicians generally won't have used it in the first place. But if we get them into Unicode we can provide consistent tools for authors. Regarding text figures (AKA old-style numbers, right?), they don't have semantic differences which is why they don't have their own unique slots.